# Which Graphical Subsystem for Touchscreen Kiosk Development

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-interface, embedded, kiosk

I'm starting a hobby project in which I would like to have a graphical, touchscreen interface for interacting with a kiosk-like device running on top of Windows XP Embedded.  For development of a rich UI experience, I was considering using WPF.  However, a number of demonstration videos that I have come across have used Silverlight, while I haven't seen a single WPF demonstration.

It was my understanding that Silverlight was targeted towards website developers, while WPF was more targeted towards desktop development.

So this question has two parts.  Firstly, what is the recommended graphical subsystem for development of a rich UI experience on a kiosk-like device hosted on the Windows XP embedded platform?  Secondly, if it is Silverlight, which version is suggested (1.0 or 2.0) and why?

Comment: Do you have more infor regarding those Silverlight demos? I'd like to see them. Tanks

Comment: The video isn't that great, but here's the one I saw.

http://www.microsoft.com/winme/0809/34284/34284_WindowsEmbedded_MBR.asx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that WPF works fine on embedded. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2006/07/10/661539.aspx) the second comment.

I think that your choice should be dependent on the type of kyosk you want to build. Some kyosks are just an open browser page. And then you have stuff like Microsoft Surface that can be used like an horizontal kyosk :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend also WPF, have done few kiosk apps using it.

also I would recommend http://fpscomponents.com/Product.aspx?id=8 as a virtual touch screen keyboard software component. it's done in WPF and very flexible and customizable.

User can define custom theme(skin), layout and language of keyboard. guys are working with customers and hear theirs voice so any suggestions might be accepted.